# Why does block.coinbase returns a value in a view function?

Tags: solidity

This [answer states](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/92108/84176) the following about `block.coinbase`:

```
block.coinbase points to the miner node which included the transaction in its block.
```

So why does the below function returns a value if it doesn't write the blockchain and the tx doesn't get mined?

```
  function getCoinbase() external view returns (address) {
    return block.coinbase;
  }
```

After calling it I get the address of a validator node, but it is not a state writing function. Why do I get any results then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason every member of `block.` returns a value when called in a view function, it uses the latest available data (so here, the coinbase of the last mined block (or an older one if you're on a fast chain and the node that treated this request is lagging behind)